# Generating binary number using bitset causing segmentation fault in c++

Tags: c++, vector, std, bitset

Generating binary representation of numbers from 0 to 255. This is causing segmentation fault. Kindly enlighten.

```
    vector<bitset<7>> vb;
    for (i = 0; i < 256; i++)
    {
        bitset<7> b(i);
        vb[i] = b;
    }

    //print 
    for(i=0;i<256;i++){
        cout<<vb[i]<<"\n";
```

Comment: you either need to resize upfront or use push_back, youre currently trying to assign into an empty vector (if you had used .at(), i believe it would have thrown an exception but operator[] doesnt do those checks, except maybe with some debug compilation flags)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your vector is of size 0. Either use

```
vb.push_back(b);
```

or initialize a size like:

```
vector<bitset<7>> vb(256);
```

Answer (score 2):

When you declare your vector it is empty

```
vector<bitset<7>> vb;
```

you can initialize it with a given size

```
vector<bitset<7>> vb(256);
```

Otherwise simply assigning to the empty vector will be writing out of bounds since it has not (re)allocated memory for the elements you are trying to access

```
vb[i] = b;
```

Comment: Got it @Cory! Thanks!